# ¿Cómo eliminar un elemento de una BBDD preguntando al usuario que elemento quiere eliminar?

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer la siguiente funcionalidad para un programa:
Tengo una base de datos con una tabla de productos, el usuario selecciona una opción que es "Retirar producto" y el programa le pedirá el nombre del producto que desea retirar. Lo que quiero es hacer que con poner una parte del nombre ya detecte que artículo es y lo elimine.

Estoy usando la librería sqlite3 para manejar la BBDD.
Sé que la línea usual para eliminar un elemento sería:

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBRE='?'", nombre_producto)
conexion.commit()
```

La duda es como hacer para pasar la variable nombre_producto (tal y como está escrito no funciona) y lo de detectar el producto sin necesidad de poner todo el nombre

Pongo un ejemplo:

```
nombre_producto=input("Introduce el nombre del producto que desea eliminar: ")
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBRE='?'", nombre_producto)
cursor.commit()


El producto está guardado como "Babolat Pure Drive 2015"
Quiero que con que el usuario introduzca Babolat o Babolat Pure Drive se elimine
```

Comment: podrias mostrar tu codigo para darte un solución en base a ello, ademas lee [ask] para que mejores tu pregunta :)

Comment: EL entrecomillado alrededor de `?` sobra, `cursor.execute("DELETE FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBRE=?", (nombre_producto, ))` debería funcionar. en cuanto a lo segundo, tienes varias opciones desde la cláusula [LIKE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like), expresiones regulares,  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias eliminar por medio de un 'like'.

`cursor.execute("DELETE FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBRE LIKE %?%", nombre_producto)`

El único problema es que estarias eliminando todos los nombres que coincidan con lo que pusiste, problablemente sea más de uno.

Te recomiendo hacer el delete pasando el id del producto para asegurar que solo borres uno.

Referencias:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm
- https://attakatara.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/crud-sql-facil-en-python/